# Out of 15 controls i need to select one of them and able to click on other controls

Tags: automation, tosca

I have 15 controls with the same properties, and I want to scan one of them and then be able to click on any of the other control using TOSCA.

Comment: read this [ask]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.